# Is there any way to kill or end a process in "disk sleep"

Tags: kill, io, process-management

I am running Linux Mint 18.2 with KDE Plasma. Recently I noticed that most of the times I copy large files to removable drives the process hangs just before finish.

I opened KSysGuard and saw that the process of `file.so` is in `disk sleep`.
When this happens the process seems not receiving any `kill` or `end` signal.
I decided to reboot, opened a `terminal` in `Konsole` and ran `reboot` command.
But the reboot also got stuck in the middle! I had to press the power button and force shutdown my laptop.

Now I want to know is it impossible to `kill` or `end` a process that is in `I/O Sleep` state ?

Comment: For some time I'm experiencing a problem where processes end up in *disk sleep* state for a longer period, and dropping caches with `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` gets them out of it most of the time. I don't know why that is, I suspect a multi-core deadlock problem. Maybe it helps in your case, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a process is in an `uninterruptible sleep` state, then no, you cannot kill or otherwise end the process until it exits that state.  While in that state, the process has invoked a system call on the kernel, and the kernel code executing on the behalf of the process has blocked the process waiting for some event to happen.

Note that this question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/223644/5161900